# Program not entering into for-loop

Tags: javascript

I'm currently in a Computer Science class at my high school and am writing a program to simulate Conway's Game of Life. I am writing the program in the Code Studio "App Lab" which uses JavaScript and is what we have been learning in. It has a smartphone on the left which you design for.

It's been going all fine and dandy so far, but I am working on trying to draw the cells on the screen and my program refuses to enter into the for loop which will draw the cells (which are represented as buttons). The function which draws the CellBoard, is called drawBoard and is a method inside of the CellBoard object.

```
function Cell(x, y, id) {
  //base unit for the program, can be either dead or alive based on Conway's 
  //Game of Life Rules
  this.xPos = x;
  this.yPos = y;
  this.id = "cell" + id;
  this.alive = false;
  this.aliveNextTurn = false;
  this.aliveNeighbors = 0;
  this.age = 0;

 this.swapState = function(){
    if(this.alive){
      this.alive = false;
    }
    else{
      this.alive = true;
    }
 };
}

function CellBoard(width, height){
  //the board of cells, this object will house all the methods for the rule 
  //checking and state setting
  this.board = [];
  var count = 0;
  for(var x = 0; x<width; x++){
    var boardY =[];
    for(var y = 0; y<height; y++){
      boardY.push(new Cell(x,y,count));
      count++;
    }
    this.board.push(boardY);
  }

  this.drawBoard = function(){
    //draws the board of cells on the screen as buttons so that the user can 
    //initially set them
    setScreen("simulationScreen");
    //console.log("screen set");
    //console.log("starting button making");
    for(var i = 0; i<this.width; i++){  //<----the problem is here
      //console.log("starting loop");
      for(var j = 0; j<this.height; j++){
        //console.log("making button");
        button(this.board[i][j].id, "test");
        setPosition(this.board[i][j].id, 20+(280/i), 20+(280/j), 280/i, 280/j);
        setProperty(this.board[i][j].id, "background-color", rgb(0,0,0)); //black background by default
        //console.log(getProperty(this.board[i][j].id, "x"));
      }
    }
    //console.log("done drawing board");
  };
}

var testBoard = new CellBoard(3, 3);
testBoard.drawBoard();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here are the console logs from the function that has the problem:

```
screen set
starting button making
done drawing board
```

Comment: If you fling code at us and complain, "It doesn't work!"  you'll most likely get treated poorly.  You should read the FAQ for suggestions on how to ask a proper question.

Comment: If you're calling cellBoard, it has to be getting in to the for loop, you just aren't getting the results you expected. Have you looked at console output. You could add some console logging to find out where things are breaking down.

Comment: @Difster It enters into the function and then changes the screen but then just skips the for-loop, I'll add the console logs with the debugs uncommented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like in your for loop in the `drawBoard` function, you use `this.width` and `this.height`. However you never set `this.width` and `this.height`. In the initialization code in the CellBoard class, you should be setting `this.width = width`. It might be skipping the for loop because `this.width` is undefined which doesn't satisfy the for loop condition.

As well, you use the `this` keyword in your `drawBoard` function. Within a function like that, `this` will refer to the function and not the object. Instead in the initialization code, you may want to create a variable to hold `this`. You can do `cell_board = this` in the initialization code and then use `cell_board.width` instead in the `drawBoard` function.